# Combine multiple SQL queries in 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I kinda got stuck at trying to combine a few queries.
What I got is the table holding sort of statistics and reference to another table.

to get statistics report I'm running (short version):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
from [Actions] 
where date between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-01 23:59:59' 
  AND [Action]='request'
```

The question is if I want to get every-day statistics during the specified time period, how should this query look like? I understand if I change start and end dates, I'll get statistics for the whole specified period and not grouped by day. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `GROUP BY date` after eleminating the time part like so:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [date], 121) ByDay, COUNT(id) 
FROM [Actions] 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-01 23:59:59' 
  AND [Action]='request'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [date], 121)
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something! Thanks, but I'm guessing the right form will be to use 101 and not 121 to prevent the query to group records by minutes and seconds. am I right?

Comment: @AlexD - I think the two will work for you. `121` will work since it will get only the first 10 character by `varchar(10)` which are the date part only.

Comment: Anyways, thanks so much for reminding me how does GROUP BY works!